# Matomo Setup highly Unstable

Tags: matomo

I’m having trouble with my matomo in my openshift. This matomo is rather unstable.

When I start the pod motomo runs fine for a short time (very short time). Then matomo starts to respond with http 504 regularly … eventualy beeing unable to process any request successfully and respond with 504 only.

My guess is that matomo tries (lots of) communication with the internet. My openshift is not allowed to communication with the internet. Could this be the cause of trouble?

What is the recommended setup for matomo in general and matomo in openshift in particular?

I recently updated to matomo 4. Looks a tiny little bit more stable but still ways to go for production use.

Best Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you're still having the issue but if your container has limited internet connectivity, then there might be something to it. AFAIK by default Matomo has Provider plugin enabled, which performs external DNS lookup. That takes place as part of tracking requests processing, and could fail in your case. Check this: [Matomo optimisation how-to](https://matomo.org/docs/optimize-how-to/)

> Tracker API: if the ‘Provider’ plugin is activated in your Matomo, the Internet provider by doing a reverse DNS lookup which adds a few milliseconds overhead.

Other than that, I suppose you're speaking about timeouts on tracking requests - you could enable tracker debug mode (in config.ini.php) to see the output of request processing.

If this is about reporting queries - then this may be broader subject, as this may be issue with archiving timeouts.

If this will reach you and you would respond, please specify if this is about tracking or reporting requests :)